# ReactIntl: How to use ReactIntl's <FormattedMessage> tag inside const?

Tags: reactjs, localization, internationalization, react-intl

```
const HEADER = [
{label: "NAME", key: "name"},
{label: "NUMBER", key: "mobilenumber"}
];
```

I'm implementing React-intl on my existing react application. whereas in my application, there are some table headers dynamically coming from the const. Is there any way to format the **label** value in **const** using React-intl? Thanks in advance.

i can able to format the below one like:

Actual code:

```
const details = ["Contact Number", "Address"]
```

with react-intl:

```
const details = [<FormattedMessage id="number"/>,<FormattedMessage id="address"/>]  --->this works
```

Comment: can you add the code for the `const` your talking about and the data snippet as well?

Comment: @sathyareddy I already added the const above. i have a **HEADER** const, inside I'm having array of object(label and key).  Is it possible to format the label value?